# Display content first when the user clicks on text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made an little sketch where you can see how my view looks actually and how i want it to be: [image]

How you hopefully can recognize i want, that when the user clicks on one chapter, its subchapters are displayed in an box on the right side.

Actually my view template looks like this:

```
<% @chapter.each do |chapter| %>
  <%= chapter.number %><%= chapter.description %>
  </p>
  <% chapter.subchapter.split(';').each do |subchapter| %>
     <%= subchapter %>
     </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I hope you can give my suggestions, how to solve my issue!

Comment: Can you post the resulting markup? This problem can be solved with plain HTML and jQuery, so I think you'll be more likely to get the help you want if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
<% @chapter.each do |chapter| %>
  <%= chapter.number %><%= link_to_function chapter.description, "$(\"#\"+#{chapter.id}\").toggle()" %>
  </p>
<div id=<%= chapter.id %> style="display: none;">
  <% chapter.subchapter.split(';').each do |subchapter| %>
     <p>
     <%= subchapter %>
     </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```